# jsf messages: adding link

Tags: html, jsf, richfaces

Currently in JSF, all HTML contained within a message (`rich:messages` tag) is escaped and just shows up as the markup. For example, in my backing bean, I have:

```
createMessage("Title created successfully with product number: <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">" + product.getProductNumber() + "</a>.");
```

where `createMessage()` is just a helper function that adds a new Message to the faces context and is then viewable in my `rich:messages` tag.

When this message is created, my message simply shows up with the escaped HTML:

```
Title created successfully with product number: <a href="http://www.example.com">1234</a>.
```

Is there any way to avoid this and just provide an actual link in the message instead?

Thanks in advance

~Zack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution is to create a new renderer.

I've done this for ***h:messages*** as I wanted to separate the messages of different severities into separate divs. If you never want to use the default renderer then it's a good option.

The standard class that you would overwrite/extend is:

```
public class MessagesRenderer extends HtmlBasicRenderer
```

You would just use a ResponseWriter that doesn't escape the text. The concrete class is the HtmlResponseWriter which escapes the text. You could extend this and overwrite the

```
public void writeText(Object text, String componentPropertyName)
```

so that it doesn't use HtmlUtils.

Then just add your new renderer to faces-config.xml

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Messages</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Messages</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.mypackage.MessagesRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: Nice. For future reference: a year later, the same approach with full code was posted at [Embedding a link (or other html) in a JSF message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356546/embedding-a-link-or-other-html-in-a-jsf-message/3358402#3358402).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to create your own version of `rich:messages` that has an `escape` attribute, like `h:outputText`, so you can disable HTML escaping.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery you can unescape the xml characters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".esc").each(function(i) {
                var h = $(this).html();                
                h = h.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
                h = h.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
                $(this).html(h);
            });
        });
        //]]> 
     </script>
```