# Embedding a link (or other html) in a JSF message

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to embed a link in a JSF message, is this possible?

When I try it, the rendered html of the h:messages tag escapes the html characters.  I tried setting the escape attribute of the h:messages tag to false, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in the standard JSF implementation. The component and the renderer doesn't officially support this attribute. You can however homegrow a renderer which handles this.

Since this is a pretty common requirement/wish, I thought to take a look what's all possible.

First some background information: JSF by default uses [`ResponseWriter#writeText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html#writeText%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29) to write the tag body, which escapes HTML by default. We'd like to let it use [`ResponseWriter#write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) instead like as with `<h:outputText escape="false" />`. We'd like to extend the `MessagesRenderer` of the standard JSF implementation and override the `encodeEnd()` method accordingly. But since the `MessagesRenderer#encodeEnd()` contains pretty a lot of code (~180 lines) which we prefer not to copypaste to just change one or two lines after all, I found it better to replace the `ResponseWriter` with a custom implementation with help of [`ResponseWriterWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriterWrapper.html) wherein the `writeText()` is been overriden to handle the escaping.

So, I ended up with this:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper;
import javax.faces.render.FacesRenderer;

import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MessagesRenderer;

@FacesRenderer(componentFamily="javax.faces.Messages", rendererType="javax.faces.Messages")
public class EscapableMessagesRenderer extends MessagesRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        final ResponseWriter originalResponseWriter = context.getResponseWriter();

        try {
            context.setResponseWriter(new ResponseWriterWrapper() {

                @Override
                public ResponseWriter getWrapped() {
                    return originalResponseWriter;
                }

                @Override
                public void writeText(Object text, UIComponent component, String property) throws IOException {
                    String string = String.valueOf(text);
                    String escape = (String) component.getAttributes().get("escape");
                    if (escape != null && !Boolean.valueOf(escape)) {
                        super.write(string);
                    } else {
                        super.writeText(string, component, property);
                    }
                }
            });

            super.encodeEnd(context, component); // Now, render it!
        } finally {
            context.setResponseWriter(originalResponseWriter); // Restore original writer.
        }
    }
}
```

In spite of the `@FacesRenderer` annotation, it get overriden by the default `MessagesRenderer` implementation. I suspect here a bug, so I reported [issue 1748](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1748). To get it to work anyway, we have to fall back to the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Messages</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Messages</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.EscapableMessagesRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Then, to trigger it, just do:

```
<h:messages escape="false" />
```

And it works! :)

---

Note: the above affects `<h:messages>` only. To do the same for `<h:message>`, just do the same, but replace *anywhere* `"Messages"` by `"Message"` (component family, renderer type and classnames).

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I arrived at the same solution today as well (and filed the same bug https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1750) I used the delegator pattern for my response writer, but I think I prefer what you did with the wrapper.  Thanks!

Comment: A new link for the reported issue:
http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1750

Comment: This code does not works wits the MyFaces JSF 2 implementation right?

Comment: @Mr.Pichler: You'd indeed extend its own one. These days there's `<o:messages>` as alternative. http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/messages

Comment: With this solution, we are replacing the `ResponseWritter` globally. So will there be a case that right after you set the new `ResponseWriter` some user will able to see the result that is not escaped where it should?

Comment: I guess my question is this: before we set the `ResponseWritter` to original, will there be a case that other classes call getResponseWriter and get the "modified one"?

Comment: Only component's original `encodeEnd()` (or error pages, I've edited the answer to fix that).

Comment: @BalusC I get error `Attribute escape according invalid for tag messages to TLD` at the line `<h:messages escape="false"/>`. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: @user1766169: It's the IDE who's pretending to be smarter than it is. Just ignore it. It runs fine, right?

Comment: @user1766169: perhaps you're unexpectedly using legacy JSP instead of its in 2009 introduced successor Facelets. All JSF 2.x answers here are targeted on Facelets as JSP has been deprecated since then.

Comment: @BalusC Ok. Thanks! Thats probebly the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `escape="false"` attributed you need is provided by the OmniFaces [`<o:messages>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/messages). The OmniFaces utility library is available for JSF 2.

<sup>I posted this solution mentioned by @BalusC's comment as an answer since this is the most straightforward solution.</sup>