# Embedding a link (or other html) in a JSF (1.2) message(s)

Tags: jsf-1.2

According to this Question...

[Embedding a link (or other html) in a JSF message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356546/embedding-a-link-or-other-html-in-a-jsf-message)

... and a relating blog post from BalusC...

http://balusc.blogspot.ch/2010/07/using-html-in-jsf-messages.html

... I only have to remove the import and the annotation of FacesRenderer. There is an equivalent in JSF 1.2 though called Renderer, but this class doesn't cover annotations.

Anyway, I get the following error in my Browser:

> Attribute escape invalid for tag messages according to TLD

How can I resolve this issue? Because it seems that adding costum renderer and attribute for a component legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom attribute requires [custom TLD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html) to work properly...